# Nginx location expressions

Tags: nginx

I have problem when im using **~*** for case insensitive expression

this will download my **index.php**  instead of showing this file.
maybe i do not have a correct understanding of this expression. can you help me ?

Comment: Do you have `location ~ \.php`? Please post your `nginx.conf`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem

When I want to use an insensitive expression, I should create 
another location block to route the query to proper location in webserver! 
Thank you for the response !